# using javascript in my code is not showing rows in the table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to follow this example in my code:

https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/yygKmO

I  am trying to incorporate javascript in my code from the above example, but when I run the code, i don't see any rows in the table.
It seems that Javascript is not getting incorporated in my code.

```
**<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
    var table = document.querySelector("table"),
  table_meta_container = table.querySelector("thead"),
  table_data_container = table.querySelector("tbody"),
  data = [
    { firstName: "Scooby", lastName: "Doo", birth: 1969 },
    { firstName: "Yogi", lastName: "Bear", birth: 1958 },
    { firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Cat", birth: 1940 },
    { firstName: "Jerry", lastName: "Mouse", birth: 1940 },
    { firstName: "Fred", lastName: "Flintstone", birth: 1960 }
  ],
  n = data.length;

var createTable = function (src) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    curr_item,
    curr_p;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    curr_item = document.createElement("tr");
    curr_item.classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? "odd" : "even");
    data[i].el = curr_item;

    for (var p in data[i]) {
      if (p !== "el") {
        curr_p = document.createElement("td");
        curr_p.classList.add("prop__value");
        curr_p.dataset.propName = p;
        curr_p.textContent = data[i][p];
        curr_item.appendChild(curr_p);
      }
    }

    frag.appendChild(curr_item);
  }

  table_data_container.appendChild(frag);
};

var sortTable = function (entries, type, dir) {
  entries.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[type] < b[type]) return -dir;
    if (a[type] > b[type]) return dir;
    return 0;
  });

  table.dataset.sortBy = type;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    entries[i].el.style.order = i + 1;

    if (
      (i % 2 === 0 && entries[i].el.classList.contains("even")) ||
      (i % 2 !== 0 && entries[i].el.classList.contains("odd"))
    ) {
      entries[i].el.classList.toggle("odd");
      entries[i].el.classList.toggle("even");
    }
  }
};

createTable(data);

table_meta_container.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    var t = e.target;

    if (t.classList.contains("prop__name")) {
      if (!t.dataset.dir) {
        t.dataset.dir = 1;
      } else {
        t.dataset.dir *= -1;
      }

      sortTable(data, t.dataset.propName, t.dataset.dir);
    }
  },
  false
);

  </script>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  
</head>

<body>

   

<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='prop__name' data-prop-name='firstName'>First Name</th>
        <th class='prop__name' data-prop-name='lastName'>Last Name</th>
        <th class='prop__name' data-prop-name='birth'>Birth</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `html` has to run first to create the dom and then your `js`.
If you move your `js` to the bottom your code will work.

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  
</head>

<body>

   

<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='prop__name' data-prop-name='firstName'>First Name</th>
        <th class='prop__name' data-prop-name='lastName'>Last Name</th>
        <th class='prop__name' data-prop-name='birth'>Birth</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>**
 <script>
    var table = document.querySelector("table"),
  table_meta_container = table.querySelector("thead"),
  table_data_container = table.querySelector("tbody"),
  data = [
    { firstName: "Scooby", lastName: "Doo", birth: 1969 },
    { firstName: "Yogi", lastName: "Bear", birth: 1958 },
    { firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Cat", birth: 1940 },
    { firstName: "Jerry", lastName: "Mouse", birth: 1940 },
    { firstName: "Fred", lastName: "Flintstone", birth: 1960 }
  ],
  n = data.length;

var createTable = function (src) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    curr_item,
    curr_p;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    curr_item = document.createElement("tr");
    curr_item.classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? "odd" : "even");
    data[i].el = curr_item;

    for (var p in data[i]) {
      if (p !== "el") {
        curr_p = document.createElement("td");
        curr_p.classList.add("prop__value");
        curr_p.dataset.propName = p;
        curr_p.textContent = data[i][p];
        curr_item.appendChild(curr_p);
      }
    }

    frag.appendChild(curr_item);
  }

  table_data_container.appendChild(frag);
};

var sortTable = function (entries, type, dir) {
  entries.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[type] < b[type]) return -dir;
    if (a[type] > b[type]) return dir;
    return 0;
  });

  table.dataset.sortBy = type;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    entries[i].el.style.order = i + 1;

    if (
      (i % 2 === 0 && entries[i].el.classList.contains("even")) ||
      (i % 2 !== 0 && entries[i].el.classList.contains("odd"))
    ) {
      entries[i].el.classList.toggle("odd");
      entries[i].el.classList.toggle("even");
    }
  }
};

createTable(data);

table_meta_container.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    var t = e.target;

    if (t.classList.contains("prop__name")) {
      if (!t.dataset.dir) {
        t.dataset.dir = 1;
      } else {
        t.dataset.dir *= -1;
      }

      sortTable(data, t.dataset.propName, t.dataset.dir);
    }
  },
  false
);

  </script>
```